# Can deleting a django Model with a ManyToManyField create orphaned database rows?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

If I have two classes A and B with a many to many relationship and I want to delete an instance of A, do I need to remove all of its related Bs first or will Django sort that out for me?

I obviously don't want to leave orphaned rows in the join table.

Does it make any difference if the ManyToMany field is declared on class A or B?

Does it make any difference if there are additional fields on a join class specified using the "through" parameter?

Comment: Bah! :)  Actually I want to know what the "correct" way to do it is.  I don't want it acting differently in production, on a different database back end and so forth.

Comment: the "correct" way is to merely delete the instance of `A` and let Django remove the M2M for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have two classes A and B with a many to many relationship and I want to delete an instance of A, do I need to remove all of its related Bs first or will Django sort that out for me?

Short answer: Django will sort that out for you.

> Does it make any difference if the ManyToMany field is declared on class A or B?

As far as I know, no, it does not make a difference.

> Does it make any difference if there are additional fields on a join class specified using the "through" parameter?

I haven't tried this myself but I don't see why there should be a problem.